# How to make conditional styles in Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, conditional-statements, gif

I'm trying to make Paperclip convert every image to JPG unless it is an animated gif. Is there any way to specify a conditional style or I have to make a processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know Paperclip does not have any build in functionality to solve your problem except custom processors. You can do some thing like this:

```
module Paperclip
  class ConditionalConverter < Thumbnail
    def initialize(file, options = {}, attachment = nil)
      super(file, options, attachment)
      @format = :jpg unless self.animated?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`ImageMagick` should done it for you. For that you should add `:jpg` to your styles:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :thumb => ["32x32#", :jpg] }
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)